# How to find |>>> operator in Scala/Play! API

Tags: scala, playframework

I've encountered this code in a Play! application :

```
val total: Future[Int] = enumerator |>>> cumulated
```

`enumerator` is of type `play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator` and `cumulated` is of type `play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee` but checking both these API's does not define the `|>>>` operator.

How to to find the `|>>>` operator ? I think it's mentioned in one of the Play! docs but are there steps to find it based on its operands `play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator` , `play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just clicked on the [index](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#index.index-_) and found there that it is indeed defined in [`play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator`](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator@|>>>[A](i:play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[E,A]):scala.concurrent.Future[A]).

Alternatively, you can go directly to [`play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator`](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator) and scroll down till you find it.

I guess your main problem is that you are searching for an operator. There are no operators in Scala, only methods. `|>>>` is simply a valid name for a method, and `a foo b` is simply an alternative way of writing `a.foo(b)`.

Comment: Using 'enumerator.|>>> cumulated' causes compiler error : " missing argument list for method |>>> in trait Enumerator Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected. You can make this conversion explicit by writing $bar$greater$greater$greater _ or $bar$greater$greater$greater(_) instead of $bar$greater$greater$greater." So cannot used the dot in this case ?

Comment: If you use the dot, you need the parentheses as well.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov 'If you use the dot, you need the parentheses as well.' does not seem to be correct as using .(|>>>) causes compiler error : 'identifier expected but '(' found.'

Comment: @blue-sky Parentheses around the argument, of course, as the answer says, not around the method name.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks but '|>>>.(<MY FOLD FUNCTION>)' also does not compile

Comment: @blue-sky It's `enumerator.|>>>(cumulated)`. Not any other way.

Comment: @blue-sky: I already wrote in my last sentence `a foo b` is equivalent to `a.foo(b)`. It's *not* equivalent to `a.foo b`, `a.(foo) b` `foo.(b)` or any other combination you could come up with. `a.foo(b)`. Period.